# Atlas with grouped or connected lines as coverage layer (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, atlas

I have a line layer containing sections of paths. Sections with the same ID (WID) form a hiking trail. Many of these trails are circular routes, which often have access/exit paths starting from a parking lot. I want to create a sort of "route book" using the QGIS Atlas, with the hiking trails (not the individual sections) serving as coverage layers. On each atlas page, I would like to display the length of the main route and the length of the access/exit paths or sub-routes.

I can create the atlas features for the hiking trails using a virtual layer and the ST_Union function (group by WID), but then I cannot access the access/exit paths or sub-routes anymore. How can I display the length of the main route and the sub-routes for each complete hiking trail on each atlas page?

The Linelayer with selection:
[image: The Linelayer with selection]

The Atlas-Page:
[image: The Atlas-Page]

Comment: Would be good to have more information about your data structure or sample data to test. How can you distinguish access/exit paths? Do they have a special attribute value? Then you could use aggretgate functions to group these features and calculate cumulated length.

Comment: of course! I added some information

Comment: What code did you use for the length box information?

Comment: This is just a attribute table. The length comes from a virtual field ($length) in the virtual layer. The '-,--' is just a string as "place holder"

Comment: If your access paths had a different column name for length (like, laenge2) when merging, wouldn't you get the information straight from the coverage layer?

Comment: Indeed - from the screenshots alone I also do not really understand the problem, as @gvanhavre mentions.

Comment: Okay, it seems more complicated to communicate the problem. The key is: After merging the lines (with ST_Union), I cannot access the length of the access/exit paths or sub-routes anymore (because they are merged!). I cannot share it because there are some sensitive data in it.

Comment: Some dummy data that represent the same structure as you have it. Otherwise it's difficult to understand

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your virtual layer uses a query like

```
SELECT WID, ST_UNION(geometry) AS geometry
FROM
Routen
GROUP BY
WID
```

i.e. it has the UNIONed geometry and the `WID`, I would suggest using the virtual layer geometry just for your coverage layer extents, but use the `WID` in the virtual layer data to lookup the lengths from the original data and return the result in a textbox in your print layout.

Example data:

[image]

Virtual layer:

[image]

Example expression in textbox to look up main and subroute lengths separately, joined by `WID` from virtual layer (=atlas coverage layer)

```
array_to_string(
    aggregate('Routen',
              'array_agg',
              "Category"||': '||"length"||' m',
              "WID"=attribute(@atlas_feature,'WID')
             ),
'\n ')
```

You can of course modify the expression in so many ways:

- to only show `length` instead of `"Category"||': '||"length"||' m'`
- add an extra condition to the filter such as `AND "Category" = 'Subroute'`  so that you can have a text box only showing subroute lengths
- use `sum` instead of `array_agg` as the aggregator
- get total lengths by summing up lengths without the category filter...

---

Result:

[image]